# page.evaluate not logging a returned value

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I've seen other questions with the same title but that doesn't help. I was trying to log a value returned from `page.evaluate` function but it's logging neither in the browser nor in the terminal.. here's my code

```
const pptr = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const { config, baseURL } = require("./config");

    await pptr.launch(config).then(async browser => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(baseURL, { waitUntil: "load" });

    await page.setDefaultTimeout(0);
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);

    await page.click("#pgntn > div.Pagination > ul > li:nth-child(8) > a");
    await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "load" });

    let pageNumber = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return document.querySelector("a.current").textContent;
    });

    console.log(pageNumber);
  });
})();
```

Comment: UPDATE: when I manually reload the page it logs the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a waitForSelector before the evaluate

```js
await page.waitForSelector('a.current');
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be some reasons.

1. Value isn't visible yet, so you can add `await page.waitForSelector('a.current');`
2. Page isn't fully loaded, so consider change `page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });`
3. If those solutions wouldn't help, you can still try to use `await page.reload();` and then try to get value.

A little improvement with getting value, you don't have to evaluate to browser's context, just use `const pageNumber = await page.$eval('a.current', el => el.textContent);`. It's much nicer and cleaner solution :).